# Wordpress weird characters - no fix possible?

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding

My blog has always had this:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

All MySQL tables have always been

```
utf8_general_ci
```

I recently upgraded MySQL from 5.1 to 5.6. The upgrade went well.

Wordpress is 3.8.1.

My header.php also has this as the top, so UTF8 is always been set:

> ```
> <?php 
> header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
> ?><!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
>   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
>   ...
> ```

Suddenly with all the settings as above, I am seeing these characters:  "Â"

Googling for this suggests very varied advice:

(1) Remove the `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`. If I do this, the Â character does go away, but other weird characters emerge in the text in older posts.

(2) Use a plugin to replace that character with a space. Seriously, this is such a kludge. I'd like to avoid such hacks.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you seeing the weird character all over or only at the top of the file?

Comment: All over. Mostly in the content of the post, which appears after a lot of other stuff such as header and navigation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>"/>` instead of `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`.

Comment: How would this be any different? Doesn't make any sense. It publishes the same thing. I want absolutely nothing else but utf-8 everywhere -- in the database and the frontend. It has always been this way. Anyway your suggestion doesn't sound relevant to this issue.